# efficiently writing WTForm submission to mysql

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a long wtform:

i.e.

```
Question1 = TextAreaField('What is your name?')
...
Question100=TextAreaField('Describe your role')
```

When the user submits the form, Flask retrieves the data for each question:

i.e.

```
Question1=form.Question1.data
..
Question100=form.Question100.data
```

Then I write the data to a db using sql
i.e.

```
cursor.executve("INSERT INTO table (Q1,Q100) values (%s,%s)", (Question1, Question100))
```

SQL injection is not an issue and I wish not to use SQLalchemy. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT:
Suppose some field types are FieldLists, Formfields or HiddenFields. How might I write those into the table? How might I skip over them in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast and readable solution

```
written_fields = [f for f in form if f.id in WRITE_TO_SQL_FIELDS]
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO table ({}) values ({})".format(
        ",".join(f.id for f in written_fields),
        ",".join(str(f.data) for f in written_fields),
    )
)
```

or, if you prefer filtering by type:

```
BLACKLISTED_TYPES = (wtforms.FieldList, wtforms.Formfield, wtforms.HiddenField)
written_fields = [f for f in form if not isinstance(f, BLACKLISTED_TYPES)]
```

Comment: Hi Fian, thanks for your solution. In retrospect, I could've been more detailed with the initial post. Can you tell me how I might account for or exclude `Fieldlists` or `FormFields` or `HiddenFields` when looping / writing to SQL?

Comment: Changed my answer to support field exclusion. There are at least 2 approaches: via a list of fields names that should be written to a DB, or you can filter fields by type (I don't like that approach).